# Cartoon where a kid had superpowers and a yin yang sign

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, powers

In my memory this show reminded me a lot of Ben 10 just the character didn't have a watch that contained "monsters" that he could transform into. The plot was mostly him battling evil and winning like usual. I remember watching it like in 2007-2008. One of the main things I remember about the character is that he had a yin yang sign on the left side of his left leg; it was like some kind of a bag.

Comment: some more question does the mc battle alone or with a team? Is he bald? Does the fight contains gadget or magic or pure luck ,... ?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good anime Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: He worked alone, he wasnt bald he had the same type of hair as ben 10, his fights contain gadgets mostly.

Comment: Could it be Jack Spicer from Xiaolin Showdown? I don't know about the yan yang sign but some characters where into martial arts so the sign could've appeared in more occasions.